# Regex: Match between delimiters (a letter and a special character) in a string to form new sub-strings

Tags: python-3.x, regex, substring

I was working on a certain problem where I have form new sub-strings from a main string.

For e.g.
`in_string=ste5ts01,s02,s03`

The expected output strings are `ste5ts01`, `ste5ts02`, `ste5ts03`

There could be comma(,) or forward-slash (/) as the separator and in this case the delimiters are the letter `s` and `,`

The pattern I have created so far:

```
pattern = r"([^\s,/]+)(?<num>\d+)([,/])(?<num>\d+)(?:\2(?<num>\d+))*(?!\S)"
```

The issue is, I am not able to figure out how to give the letter 's' as one of the delimiters.

Any help will be much appreciated!

Comment: Are you using `re` or the `regex` module? Where do you get `t3e5` from? Do you mean  `ste5ts01`

Comment: Hi @The fourth bird , sorry. I have edited the question!

Comment: Please clarify (by editing) "separator" and "delimiter", including the difference between the two.

Comment: You can write `str = "in_string=ste5ts01,s02,s03"`, `rgx = r'(?<==)\w+(?=s\d+,)|s\d+(?![^,])'` then `re.findall(rgx, str) #=> ['ste5t', 's01', 's02', 's03']`. At this point is should be simple to obtain the desired result, but my rudimentary knowledge of Python prevents me from providing the last bit of code. In Ruby one could write `prefix, *rest = str.scan(rgx); rest.map { |s| prefix + s } #=> ["ste5ts01", "ste5ts02", "ste5ts03"]`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You might use an approach using the [PyPi regex module](https://pypi.org/project/regex/) and named capture groups which are available in the `captures`:

```
=(?<prefix>s\w+)(?<num>s\d+)(?:,(?<num>s\d+))+
```

**Explanation**

- `=` Match literally
- `(?<prefix>s\w+)` Match `s` and 1+ word chars in group *prefix*
- `(?<num>s\d+)` Capture group *num* match `s` and 1+ digits
- `(?:,(?<num>s\d+))+` Repeat 1+ times matching `,` and capture `s` followed by 1+ digits in group *num*

Example

```
import regex as re

pattern = r"=(?<prefix>s\w+)(?<num>s\d+)(?:,(?<num>s\d+))+"
s="in_string=ste5ts01,s02,s03"

matches = re.finditer(pattern, s)
for _, m in enumerate(matches, start=1):
    print(','.join([m.group("prefix") + c for c in m.captures("num")]))
```

Output

```
ste5ts01,ste5ts02,ste5ts03
```

Comment: Even I was thinking in similar lines, but is there a way to mitigate if in_string=ste5ts01
(no commas)